# Auto 'zz' in vim after a jump

Tags: vim, command

After I make a jump to anywhere in the world, whether in the current file or a different file, is it possible to make vim automatically run `zz` (re-center on current line)?

I want this after things like search, `ctrl-o` and `ctrl-i` ... and pretty much any movement other than `hjkl`.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer but a good tip, I like
`set scrolloff=7`

Answer (score 12):

Voila:

```
" Center screen on next/previous selection.
nnoremap n nzz
nnoremap N Nzz
" Last and next jump should center too.
nnoremap <C-o> <C-o>zz
nnoremap <C-i> <C-i>zz
```

Comment: This is great, I would also add:  
" Center screen on paragraph jump  
`nnoremap } }zz`  
`nnoremap { {zz`